# OpenCV's extra module cv2.face is not known

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\asus\Google Drive\Miroir intelligent\code\Reconnaissance faciale\PyFaceRec-master\SimpleFaceRecognition\simple_face_recognition.py", line 58, in 
>       recognizer = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
>   AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'

```
    collector = cv2.face.StandardCollector_create()
```

Comment: Did you build opencv with extra modules?

Comment: No I didn't. I'm on Windows 10, how can I install those extra modules? (Is there any command line to install it with PIP?)

Comment: It's ok. I found the solution. I downloaded a file on this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) "opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl". And I typed this command {pip install opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl}

Comment: thanks anyway @QuangHoang